# How can I pass a name/value pair during runtime via ASM(Instrumentation) in a remote EJB call?

Tags: ejb, websphere, weblogic, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

**Context**

I am trying to pass a name/value pair during runtime via ASM(Instrumentation) in a remote EJB call.

[image]

The client application is a JSP that is deployed on Tomcat 7. I have used the weblogic thin client on the client application (`wlthint3client.jar`). The EJB server application, a stateless session bean, is deployed on WebLogic 12c.

Passing the name/value pair as a EJB method parameter is not an option since I am profiling the application. Hence the need for ASM/Instrumentation.

**JBoss**

For JBoss/Wildfly, I was able to figure out that the following class and method could be instrumented to pass the name/value pair.

```
Classname: org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext
Method Name: getContextData()
```

Based on my research, the getContextData method returns a Map to which I appended my name/value pair. This Map reference is sent to the server side EJB application.

**WebLogic/WebSphere**

I need an equivalent in WebLogic and WebSphere of the same context data type of an object (i.e equivalent of the above JBoss' class and method name) so that I could pass my name/value pair during runtime via ASM/instrumentation.

If you could kindly point me to some references, would appreciate your help.

Comment: That seems way too broad. It’s not even clear what “*name/value pair*” is supposed to mean. Or why you think you have to pass it via ASM/Instrumentation instead of any other way, or, *how*. You talk about a remote EJB call, but Instrumentation is a local code transformation. Where’s the relationship?